# Java replace single backslach

Tags: java, replaceall

I am writing a program that only replaces double backslash, not single backslash.

I don't quite understand how this could be working in Java:

```
"\\".replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
```

The result is `"/"`

But I am expecting it should stay unchanged, since "\" is a single backslash character, the first \ is an escape character, right?

Comment: Please also read the docs for the String `replaceAll()` method.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  `replaceAll` takes a regex expression, so that means you have to quote the backslash with a backslash: "\\".  But Java also requires you to quote backslashes, so each of those two backslashes needs to be quoted as well: "\\\\".  If you use the `replace` method instead of `replaceAll`, then the extra quoting goes away (but you also don't get regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the escape characters of java strings the string would become `\` (`\\ -> \`) while the regular expression becomes `\\` (`\\\\ -> \\`).

For a regular expression `\` is an escape character as well. Therefore the search pattern searches for `\` (`\\ -> \`) and replaces that with the given `/`.